# Type casting issue in Xquery

Tags: string, type-conversion, numbers, xquery

In XQuery when I am trying to execute the below function,

```
fn:number('10.12')
```

the result is **10.12**
but if I try to typecast it into decimal,

```
xs:decimal(fn:number('10.12'))
```

the result is
**10.1199999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625**

Can anyone help me understand what is the reason behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fn:number()` is defined to return an `xs:double`, that is a 64-bit IEEE floating point number. There is no `xs:double` that is exactly equal to the decimal value `10.12`: the only numbers that can be exactly represented are those of the form m × 2^e , where m is an integer whose absolute value is less than 253, and e is an integer between −1074 and 971, inclusive. So you get an approximation.

XQuery defines the rules for converting a string to `xs:double` by reference to the rules in XML Schema (XSD) (either version 1.0 or 1.1 at implementor discretion). XSD 1.0 required the results to be consistent with the algorithm published at

William D Clinger. How to Read Floating Point Numbers Accurately. In Proceedings of Conference on Programming Language Design and Implementation, pages 92-101. Available at: ftp://ftp.ccs.neu.edu/pub/people/will/howtoread.ps

XSD 1.1 is a bit more liberal.

But either way, you will get an `xs:double` that is not exactly equal to 10.12.

If you converted the resulting `xs:double` to a string, the chances are that it would be output as `10.12`, because the processor is allowed to generate any string that round-trips back to the supplied `xs:double` [Note 1]. But if you convert it to an `xs:decimal`, the rules say that you get "the `xs:decimal` value, within the set of `xs:decimal` values that the implementation is capable of representing, that is numerically closest to [the supplied value]". Which won't be exactly `10.12`.

As it happens, there's a community group working on XQuery 4.0 and its agenda includes a proposal to change the rules so double-to-decimal conversion follows the same rules as double-to-string conversion: see https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/410

[Note 1] That's effectively what XQuery 3.1 says. IIRC, XQuery 1.0 is more prescriptive.